# "Could not launch external web browser"

Tags: eclipse, browser

error message is "Could not launch external web browser" when running page.

I'd like to launch external web browser in eclipse.

Of course, Preference about web browser was set on.

How to solve this?

Comment: try restarting eclipse once.

Comment: did you try it with different browers? which OS? tried restarting after changing settings? any further details in the error message?

Answer (score 2):

this happen because (fighting betweeen google and window this happens 80% in original window) some time window change remove path of google produnds from temperary memory so you need to reselect path in eclipse as follows:

I got my solution by going window in eclipse->preference->general->web browser->restore default->aplly->ok->

then restart eclipse

again window->preference->general->web browser->use external web browser-> new-> select folder of google in c:/programfile/google ->ok->click search->select chrome->apply->ok.

then restart eclipse.

thats it enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting it by hand under *Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Web Browser*.

See [the details here](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-42.htm).

Comment: I know that. already set on. But external web browser do not work.

Answer (score 0):

I know it, you must modify your default browser in your OS.

Then click Window-Default system web browser in eclipse.